# Apache URL Rewrite using prefix

Tags: apache

I am trying to rewrite the url on the apache server.
What I want is to replace the url similar with regex.
For ex, test.com/abcdef.php -> test.com/124abcdef.php(if abc, prefix is 123)
        test.com/defdef.php -> test.com/456defdef.php(if def, prefix is 456)

Thanks.